# cookie possibly blocking clipboard API

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, clipboard

I have this bit of code below that essentially on click of an a tag copies the text of an input field to the clipboard and then opens a new tab where the user pastes the text.

This all works completely fine UNTIL the cookie is set. I have tried it with testing 10 of the different a tags before the cookie is set.

Once the cookie is set, the new tab will still open, the input field I am copying the text from still updates, but if I paste into notepad or the window that opens, it will be whatever was copied last and not the most up to date. If I remove the cookie and reload everything goes back to how it should function.

So I am not sure why the cookie being set would stop the clipboard from updating.

```
 //Set Cookie Function
 function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    const d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    let expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

//Get Cookie Function
function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    // because unescape has been deprecated, replaced with decodeURI
    //return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
} 

$(document).on('click', '.pop-top ul li a', function() {
    var copiedRole = $(this);
    $('#copyText').val(copiedRole.text());
    navigator.clipboard.writeText($('#copyText').val());
    
    var acknowledgeExists = getCookie("acknowledge");

    if(acknowledgeExists == null) {
        $('#copyMessage, .frosted').addClass('show');
    } else {
        window.open('[redacted]', '_blank');
    }
});

//Create Cookies
$("#acknowledge").on('click', function() {
    $('#copyMessage, .frosted').removeClass('show');
    window.open('[redacted]', '_blank');

    if($('#never').is(':checked')) {
        setCookie("acknowledge", "yes", 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: So it turns out that the issue was the window.open firing immediately since the cookie prevent the notification box with the button to open the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that it was not the cookie, but the window.open firing immediately. MDN docs for the clipboard API note that the tab must be active. So even though my code has the write to clipboard function before the cookie check, it still would fire quick enough to prevent it.

While not an ideal solution wrapping the window.open in the cookie if/else in a setTimeout for 1 second works fine.